What kind of damage would a maser (microwave weapons) cause to targets and bystanders?
If you don't know, a maser is the "father" of a laser, it is an acronym for microwave amplification by stimulated emission of radiation.
Unfortunately, I'm facing difficulties in finding information about masers. Google gets confused by the word and just shows results talking about lasers or crowd control using non-lethal microwave weapons.

Assuming that a infrared laser (pulsed or not) weapon emits a total of 200,000 joules of energy, it would have a similar power delivery to a single projectile from an A-10's cannon.
However, the laser would be so intense that anyone looking at either the beam or the target would be instantly and permanently blinded (I think).  Lasers also need to avoid the vapour of the target material, which would completely absorb the heat from the beam and stop it from dealing further damage.
Now, what would a maser do?
What kind of damage would it deal to armored targets and/or human bystanders.
Pulsed or not, emitted through a laser induced plasma channel or not (that is how an electrolaser works, but you can replace the electricity with radiation, such as microwaves).

Can you fool people into walking into it and closing the door then set it to 'Cook'?

Not sure I get the question - how do you mean "what would a MASER do?"? Can you specify the material you're hitting with it. Could you not find the Wikipedia article on MASERs?

@Escapeddentalpatient. Added the type of target. And yes, I read the wikipedia article about masers, but they don't enter on details about maser/microwave weapons.

Could you edit down to a single focused problem for us to solve? At present you seem to have endless physics question, more suited to our [physics.se] site. Generally such weapons are collimated, (i.e. go in a straight line in a beam), but it depends how you chose to focus them. (Same with LASERs, they go through a lens to stop them diverging)

@Escapeddentalpatient. I edited, hope it is better. If I posted at the physics site. Wouldn't that be considered a sci-fi/worldbuilding question since it is about weapons?

As it happens, the American Office of Naval Research is currently soliciting research proposals for Directed Energy Weapons - High Power Microwaves... See also "The new era of high-power electromagnetic weapons" by J.R. Wilson in Military and Aerospace Electronics, Nov. 19, 2019. (P.S. Human eyes don't focus microwaves. Won't be blinded unless cooked.)

P.P.S. 200 kJ is 200 MW in one millisecond. For comparison, the Russian Don-2N early warning radar system operates in the microwave band, has a radiated power of about 250 MW, and it is not itself a weapon. Yes, it can guide the weapons to the targets. The thing is, it is very easy to couple the kinetic energy of a cannon ball with the target; it is much more difficult to couple with the target the electromagnetic energy of a microwave pulse.

@AlexP Didn't those old military radars cook birds that crossed the path of the beam? I remember hearing that somewhere. It might have been a myth.

@Toph: If it is a terminally stupid bird which does not fly away when it feels itself getting cooked... But yes, personnel servicing military radars are very strongly advised to be nowhere near the antenna when it is in operation.

I don't have the time to crank this out as a [tag:hard-science] answer, but (a) no metal vehicle is under threat. Put a piece of tinfoil in your microwave to prove this. It would be spectacular to see, though. (b) It could be useful for crowd control because microwaves will pass through someone to the people beyond where a laser can only do this with enormous power. But... (c) it wouldn't be that hard to create fabric to reflect microwaves. (d) Microwaves might have problems in a smoke-filled region. (d) Energy weapons are impractical due to the power requirements. Could be wrong, though.

Without bothering to do the Maths as required for a Hard Science answer - there is no way that your Maser putting out 200 Kj of energy at the muzzle is having anywhere near the same effect on-target that a GAU-8 round has. something something inverse square law something losses something. You are gonna need a lot more energy to get something similar at anything approaching range

The biggest problem with microwave weapons is focusing the beam, without focusing the energy would be spread onto a big area limiting the damage.
We can use a Gaussian beam as a standard model for a laser. The divergence is equal to $ wavelength/(\pi*BeamWaist) $. Now we can make some assumptions. We have a MASER with a dish size of 1m at a distance of 1 km. This limits our divergence to $1/1000$. Let us use a 100GH source with a wavelength of $0.3cm$.  This gives a minimum beam waist size of $1000*0.3cm = 3m$ (assuming $\pi=3$).  And this is the perfect case. You know the exact distance to target, you have perfect optics, no thermal blooming etc.
You can't use higher frequencies without having a problem with atmospheric absorption.
Original Answer:
Not that much, maser is a terrible weapon. Assuming you use a Hydrogen maser with a 21cm wavelength then you should not be able to concentrate the beam into a target smaller than 21 cm.  The absorption would also happen on a 21cm scale. Inside a 21cm cube, there is around 10kg of water and if you dump all that energy inside you would increase the temperature by around 5 degrees. This is all assuming that the target doesn't have armour made from some microwave mesh. A metal car would deflect most of the microwaves away.

The question is tagged [tag:hard-science], meaning your answer must be backed up with citations or equations proving the answer or it's under threat of deletion. Can you improve your answer? Thanks.

I will if that is so important

I apologize, it's the nature of the [tag:hard-science] tag.

@JBH: The answer makes the obvious point that a beam of electromagnetic radiation of a given wavelength cannot really distinguish between target points separated by less than one wavelength. Do we really need a citation?

@AlexP I'm willing to invite the OP to withdraw the tag if you are. I'm convinced that most people who apply it think it's purpose is only to get a "better answer" and don't read the wiki. But the wiki's clear. Citations, equations... proof or poof. It is worth noting that the answer isn't exactly right: wavelength isn't the same as wave amplitude. That 21cm refers to a distance along the beam, not the "width" of the beam, which is signal amplitude. A description of why the claim has been made would be useful.

@JBH: The absolute minimum spot size of a laser beam is half a wavelength. Cannot be smaller even with ideal optics... Of course, with visible light this is nowhere near achievable (because visible wavelengths are tiny, and we cannot really make lenses of such tiny dimensions), but with wavelengths of tens of centimeters we may hope to come close. (Wavelength is not only along the beam: electromagnetic fields propagate spherically in all directions. What makes laser beams propagate straight is destructive interference which kills the light that strays from the true path.)

@AlexP Back to the question, do we invite the OP to shift to [tag:science-based] or not?

tomorrow I will add a nice explanation with gaussian beams
